# Get an object just by a property value

Tags: javascript, object

Let´s assume I have an object property which is passed into a function. In this case 'name' is filled with `'myObject.name'` (which has the value `'Tom'`) - so basically `'Tom'` gets passed into the function as the 'name'

```
function(name) {
    do something //non-essential for my question
}
```

Is it possible to get the object, where `'Tom'` is the property of, just by having the information `'Tom'`? Basically I´m looking to get `myObject`.

Thanks :)

Comment: It fortunately is not possible.

Comment: No. What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

All that the function knows is that one of its parameters was pointed to the string "Tom", not what else points to that string somewhere else in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can store objects within an array, filter the array to match property name of object to parameter passed to function using `for..of` loop, `Object.entries()`, which returns an array of property, values of an object.

```js
const data = Array();

const setObjectPropertyName = _name => {
    data.push({[_name]:_name});
    return data
}

const getObjectByPropertyName = prop => {
  let res = `${prop} property not found in data`;
  for (let obj of data) {
    for (let [key] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if(key === prop) return obj;
    }
  }
  return res;
}

let s = setObjectPropertyName("Tom");
let g = getObjectByPropertyName("Tom");
let not = getObjectByPropertyName("Tome");

console.log(s,"\n", g, "\n", not);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** you absolutely should not do this. I'm only posting this because it is in fact possible (with some caveats), just *really* not advisable.

Going on the assumption that this is running in the browser and it's all running in the global scope (like in a script tag), you *could* technically iterate over the `window` object, check any objects in window for a name property and determine if their name property matches the name passed to your function.

```js
var myObject = {
    name: 'Tom',
    thisIs: 'so awful',
    imSorry: true,
};

function doSomethingWithName(name) {
    for (var obj in window) {
        var tmp = window[obj];
        if (Object(tmp) === tmp && tmp.name === name) {
            return tmp;
        }
    }
}

console.log(doSomethingWithName(myObject.name));
```